# tvos - Japanese Language is changed to English after switched keyboard to Alphanumeric mode

Tags: objective-c, swift, tvos

I am working on tvOS application for a Japanese client. All the text are Japanese in app based on localization. But I observed that the Japanese keyboard in search bar is changed to English after switched keyboard to Alphanumeric mode. Is this expected behaviour or issue with tvOS searchbar keyboard? [image]

Answer (score 0):

### **Issue**

This is an iOS, iPadOS and tvOS issue. When you use a numeric keyboard, it changes the keyboard language and uses app default language, i.e. `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` variable. Probably in your case CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is `en`, that's why it transformed JIS keyboard to qwerty keyboard.

### **Solution**

Remove the following 2 lines in `info.plist`

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
```

Comment: I tried this. But first time user click on globe icon the language remains in Japanese and second time user click on globe icon then language changes English.

Comment: The world icon allows you to switch between the different keyboards you have configured. You should also check which keyboards you have specifically configured on the tvOS device on which you are running your program